# React Redux new data replacing current data instead of extend it and function only run once

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm using this package https://github.com/RealScout/redux-infinite-scroll to make infinite scroll on list of brand. Here is my code:

Container:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { actions, getBrands } from '../reducer';
import Infinite from 'react-infinite';
import InfiniteScroll from 'redux-infinite-scroll';
import SearchBox from '../components/SearchBox';
import CardList from '../components/CardList';

const { fetchBrands } = actions;

class BrandList extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchBrands({ page: 1 });
    }

    renderList() {
        const brands = this.props.brands;
        return brands.map((brand) => {
            return (
                <CardList key={brand.id} name={brand.name} avatar={brand.avatar.thumbnail} follower={brand.follows_count} />
            );
        });

    }

    toggle() {
        return this.props.isFetching;
    }

    loadMore() {
        const {lastPage, currentPage} = this.props;
        const nextPage = currentPage ? parseInt(currentPage) + 1 : 1;
        if(currentPage && currentPage <= lastPage){
            this.props.fetchBrands({page: nextPage});
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SearchBox />

                <div className="row">
                    <InfiniteScroll
                        items={this.renderList()}
                        loadMore={this.loadMore.bind(this)}
                        />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        brands: getBrands(state),
        isFetching: state.brand.isFetching,
        currentPage: state.brand.currentPage,
        lastPage: state.brand.lastPage
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchBrands })(BrandList);
```

Reducer:

```
import axios from 'axios';

// Define Types
export const types = {
    // brand list
    FETCH_BRANDS: 'fetch_brands',
    FETCH_BRANDS_SUCCESS: 'fetch_brands_success',
    FETCH_BRANDS_ERROR: 'fetch_brands_failure',
    FETCH_BRAND: 'fetch_brand',
    FETCH_BRAND_SUCCESS: 'fetch_brand_success',
    FETCH_BRAND_ERROR: 'fetch_brand_failure',
};

const { FETCH_BRANDS, FETCH_BRANDS_SUCCESS, FETCH_BRANDS_ERROR } = types;

// Define Reducer
export const INITIAL_STATE = { brands: [], brand: {}, isFetching: false, error: null, currentPage: 1 };

export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_BRANDS:
            return { ...state, isFetching: true };
        case FETCH_BRANDS_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, brands: action.payload.brands.data, currentPage: action.payload.brands.current_page, lastPage: action.payload.brands.last_page };
        case FETCH_BRANDS_ERROR:
            return { ...state, error: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

// Define Actions
export const actions = {
    fetchBrands: ({page, count = 15}) => {
        return (dispatch) => {
            dispatch({ type: FETCH_BRANDS });
            axios.get(`brands?page=${page}&count=${count}`)
                .then((response) => {
                    const {data} = response;
                    if (data.code == 200) {
                        dispatch({ type: FETCH_BRANDS_SUCCESS, payload: data });
                    }
                });
        };
    }
};

// SELECTOR
export const getBrands = (state) => state.brand.brands;
```

1. it run `loadMore` function successfully but it not extend current list, it replace it instead.
2. `loadmore` function only run once. it should run 10 times.

do I miss something on my code to make it scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
brands: [ ...state.brands, ...action.payload.brands.data]
```

like this in your `reducer`

```
case FETCH_BRANDS_SUCCESS:
     return { ...state, brands: [ ...state.brands, ...action.payload.brands.data], currentPage: action.payload.brands.current_page, lastPage: action.payload.brands.last_page };
```

Which means that you are `concat`ing current list with upcoming list (versioned data)